# BASH : How to extract text between specific curly braces and let the other be

Tags: regex, bash, sed, latex

I'm writing files in Latex and I'm looking for a way to automatically delete some color in my documents. When there is a text within a \textcolor{add|update}{...}, it should stay and evreything within a \textcolor{delete}{...} should be deleted. Of course the \textcolor should be deleted as well.

I just can't find a Regex that will match. It just take the first and the last brace of the line without cheking they belong to the textcolor.

This is my code :

```
for i in $@
do  
sed -i 's/\\textcolor{update}{\(.*\)\}/\1/g' $i
sed -i 's/\\textcolor{add}{\(.*\)\}/\1/g' $i
sed -i 's/\\textcolor{delete}{\(.*\)\}//g' $i
done
```

For example, if I have this :

> This doesn't change and \textcolor{udpate}{this is my modified
>   \textbf{text} !!} \vspace{0.3}

I get this :

> This doesn't change and this is my modified \textbf{text} !!}
>   \vspace{0.3

I should get this result :

> This doesn't change and this is my modified \textbf{text} !!
>   \vspace{0.3}

Furthermore, I also would like to be able to get that result :

> This doesn't change and \textcolor{delete}{this is my deleted
>   \textbf{text} !!} \vspace{0.3}

gives

> This doesn't change and \vspace{0.3}

So far I tried to avoid this issue with a 200 lines script but I'm pretty sure there is an easier way with sed for example.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: try `sed 's/\\textcolor{update}{\([^}]\+\)\}/\1/'` :)

Comment: I'm sorry it doesn't work (one curly brace is not in the right place) but it was close :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this in `sed` and know that it's not possible in general for regexes alone to tackle, but this perl snippet might do the trick:

```
perl -0e '$_ = <>;s/\\textcolor{(?:update|delete|add)}({((?s:[^{}]++|(?1))*)})/$2/sg; print'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i 's/\\textcolor{\(update\|add\)}{\([^}]*\)\}/\2/g;s/\\textcolor{delete}{\([^}]*\)\}//g' file
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't seem to work :

If my text contains that :

This doesn't change and \textcolor{udpate}{this is my modified \textbf{text} !!} \vspace{0.3}
This doesn't change and \textcolor{delete}{this is my deleted \textbf{text} !!} \vspace{0.3}


I get that :
This doesn't change and \textcolor{udpate}{this is my modified \textbf{text} !!} \vspace{0.3}
This doesn't change and  !!} \vspace{0.3}